# gdb python api: how to automatically import a script file

Tags: python, gdb

How do I add a python file that will load when I start `gdb`? For example, as a test I have added:

```
# /home/ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/objfile-gdb.py
print ("Hello")
```

However, when I try and load that, it doesn't seem to be working:

```
(gdb) set auto-load scripts-directory /home/ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages
(gdb) info auto-load python
No auto-load scripts.
```

How are you supposed to properly load this? I was using this [`as a reference`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/objfile_002dgdbdotext-file.html#objfile_002dgdbdotext-file).

Comment: There are a few different kinds of auto-loading. Do you want a script to be run when you direct gdb to debug a file named `objfile`, or do you want a script to be run whenever gdb is started?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the script has a bunch of helper functions, to be able to do things like easily print the stack (in a way I want it to) and other things like that. So the `objfile` is just a helper file that should load whenever `gdb` starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to is add helper functions for every gdb session, it is much easier to load your python script with `source` in [the gdb user initialization file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html), typically, `~/.gdbinit`:

```
source /home/ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/objfile-gdb.py
```

---

If you still want to use "objfile-gdb.ext" style autoload, you have to follow [the script naming convention](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/objfile_002dgdbdotext-file.html#objfile_002dgdbdotext-file):

> script-name is formed by ensuring that the file name of objfile is absolute, following all symlinks, and resolving . and .. components, and appending the -gdb.ext suffix. If this file exists and is readable, GDB will evaluate it as a script in the specified extension language.

For example, if you want to load script for a session like `gdb /usr/bin/tree`, the script should be placed `/home/ubuntu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/usr/bin/tree-gdb.py`, besides, you probably need adjust the [`auto-load safe-path` config](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading-safe-path.html).